# jQuery Select2 selecting on enter not working after first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

There is jQuery Select2 plugin on the page with multiselect option, with ajax elements search (search and load). Currently there is a problem, when searching for a first element, pressing enter causes highlighted element to appear in the selected field ( to be selected ).

But when choosing second and more elements, pressing ENTER doesn't do anything. The '`change`' event is NOT FIRED. Normally, pressing ENTER always causes highlighted element to be selected, and options drop-down to close. So probably I did something wrong in the configuration.

If someone has advanced experience with this control and suggest where the issue reside, I'd much appreciate. There is a trick that I have to do for having nice formatted selected values, in the `processSelectionItem` function, I'm replacing some of the select2.option and trigger '`change`' event.

The init code is following:

```js
$("#searchRepo").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function(params) {
      return {
        q: params.term, // search term
        page: params.page
      };
    },
    processResults: function(data, params) {
      params.page = params.page || 1;
      return {
        results: $.map(data.items, function(item) {
          return {
            id: item.id,
            text: item.name,
            fullname: item.full_name
          };
        }),
        pagination: {
          more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
        }
      }
    },
    cache: true
  },
  escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
    return markup;
  },
  minimumInputLength: 2,
  templateResult: function(cnt) {
    return cnt.fullname;
  },
  templateSelection: function(cnt) {
    return "<a onclick='return alert(\"" + cnt.id + "\");' href='#'>" + cnt.text + "</a>";
  },
  width: '100%'
}).on("change", function(e) {
  var container = $(e.target).closest("div");
  if ($(e.target).select2('val') == null) {
    $(container).find("input[type='text'].rep-recs").val('');
  } else {
    var selectedRepos = $(e.target).select2('data');
    var selectedReposStr = selectedRepos.map(function(item, index) {
      return item.text + ";" + item.id;
    }).join(", ");
    $(container).find("input[type='text'].rep-recs").val(selectedReposStr);
  }
});
$("#searchRepo").append(new Option('inserted repo', 232423432, true, true)).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.x-git.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control re-re-ate" data-placeholder="Search repo" id="searchRepo" name="searchRepo" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle example with the code and your problem, it'd be easier to get it if it's related to the data itself. You can use any endpoint from https://api.github.com/ to make data more suitable.

Comment: @dscastro that won't work, because the Select2 control is configured to use AJAX and using web API endpoint to search / load data. Unfortunately I can use that information in public. The problem is that 'change' event is not fired by Select2 when ENTER is clicked. There must be an issue in the provided configuration.

Comment: it appears to be something like a browser glitch, because it's not 100% reproducible. Sometimes, after several items being selected, the 'change' event stops firing, the options drop down list just close. I'd blame on the browser compatibility.

Comment: Do you have the same problem with a fixed list instead of a dynamic AJAX list?